# new props type react component syntax, make stateful class component from JS function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring, es6-class, react-proptypes

Consider this react Component code syntax which include prop-type:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    class MyComponent extends React.Component {
      render() {
        const children = this.props.children;
        return (
          <div>
            {children}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired
};
```

I want to apply above syntax to refactor this of this code. But I have problem in line resetHighlights: () => void.
It would be nice if someone refactor whole this blow code:

```
    type Props = {
      highlights: Array<T_ManuscriptHighlight>,
      resetHighlights: () => void
    };

    const updateHash = highlight => {
      location.hash = `highlight-${highlight.id}`;
    };

    function Sidebar({ highlights, resetHighlights }: Props) {
      return (
        <div>
         ...
        </div>
      );
    }
```

export default Sidebar;

also I want to add function like below inside state-full class but I got error:

```
 togglePersonsHandler = () => {
        const show = this.state.showPersons;
        this.setState({showPersons: !show});
    };
```

Comment: are you asking if someone can refactor code for you? I am not sure that is what SO is for

Comment: Some how yes I don't know how to handle this form of propTypes.
  resetHighlights: () => void ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that file is using either flow or typescript to provide static typing, rather than prop-types. If you wanted to remove the typescript/flow usage, the best equivalent you could do with prop-types would be

```
Sidebar.propTypes = {
  highlights: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({...})),
  resetHighlights: PropTypes.func
}
```

May want to stick with Typescript/flow if the codebase is using it a lot though; type safety can be nice.